# Going crazy with these mouseEvent methods in Java

Tags: java

A week into it, and I am just banging my head up against this problem.  It should be a simple excersise:

I have a rectangle.  I click and drag the rectangle on an x axis.  The rectangle should only move within a set bounding area (the canvas), so if the canvas is 200 px wide, then the x coordinate should only go from 0 to `getWidth()-RECTANGLE_WIDTH`.

Simple enough, but I just can not get the darn thing to work.

Below is my unwieldy code.

I have attached two GLabels to view coordinates.  I noticed that the mouseMoved label will only display coordinates within the canvas (what I want), but the mouseDragged label will go negative, and will also show coordinates beyond the canvas-this is also where the rectangle object movement is being controlled.  Im'm not sure why those two behaviors are different.

Right now, my statement below:

```
if ((gobj.getX()) > 0 && (gobj.getX()) < (APPLICATION_WIDTH - PADDLE_WIDTH)){
     gobj.move(e.getX() - lastX, 0);                
}
```

what that statement does so far is get the rectangle to the edge, but then it just sticks there and won't return.  I'm pulling my hair out on this thing...

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import acm.graphics.*;
import acm.program.*;

/** This class displays a mouse-draggable rectangle and oval */

public class DragObject extends GraphicsProgram {

private static final int PADDLE_WIDTH = 150;
public static final int APPLICATION_WIDTH = 700;

    public void run() {

        GRect rect = new GRect(100, 100, 150, 100);
        rect.setFilled(true);
        rect.setColor(Color.RED);   
        add(rect);

        label2 = new GLabel ("");
        add(label2, 300, 400);


        label = new GLabel ("");
        add(label, 300, 300);
        addMouseListeners();


    }

    /* these coordinates are never going beyond the canvas-even if the 
     * mouse does...this is good...i want this   */

    public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e){

        label2.setLabel("Coordinates:" + e.getX() + ", " + e.getY());

    }

/** Called on mouse press to record the coordinates of the click */
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
        lastX = e.getX();
        lastY = e.getY();
        gobj = getElementAt(lastX, lastY);

    }

/** Called on mouse drag to reposition the object */
    public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) { 

          if ((gobj.getX()) > 0 && (gobj.getX()) < (APPLICATION_WIDTH - PADDLE_WIDTH)){
            gobj.move(e.getX() - lastX, 0);

           } 

            lastX = e.getX();


            /* This label is active when i click the object, and does go into negative 
             * numbers and still counts even when off the canvas...*/
            label.setLabel("Coordinates:" + e.getX() + ", " + e.getY());
    }

/* Instance variables */

private GLabel label2;
private GLabel label;
private GObject gobj;   /* The object being dragged */
private double lastX;   /* The last mouse X position */
private double lastY;   /* The last mouse Y position */
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can drag out of a component, even out of a window, quite by design in order to support drag and drop.

For drag events you just have to constrain the event location to within it's container:

```
static public final int MAX_X=(CANVAS_WIDTH - PADDLE_WIDTH);

...

public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) { 
    int px=Math.max(0,Math.min(e.getX(),MAX_X));
    int dx=(px-lastX);

    if(dx!=0) { 
        gobj.move(dx); 
        lastX=px;
        }
    }
```

---

After sleeping on it, and re-reading the comments, I have an idea where the problem might lie - in the code provided GObject is not shown, nor is how it's created/initialized.  So it's hard to guess at the context for the code in the question.

I would wager that the paddle is created to be initially in the middle (perhaps middle/bottom) of the canvas.  The code above, and in the question, only constrains a delta to prevent the delta from exceeding the bounds of the canvas - it does not account for the initial position of the paddle.  That is, if the paddle starts out at x=350, and the delta allows for a total of 700-150=550, then the constrained delta will allow the paddle to move to 350-550=-200, the paddle will move to 200 pixels beyond the left edge.

So you need to pass the move method the upper bounds and constrain the resulting position to 0 <= px <= UPPER... something like:

```
    ...
    if(dx!=0) { 
        gobj.moveX(dx,MAX_X); 
        lastX=px;
        }
    ...
```

GObject:

```
public void moveX(int dlt, int max) {
    positionX=Util.limitInt((positionX+dlt),0,max);
    }
```

Util:

```
/**
 * Limit the range of a number to the specified values.
 */
static public int limitInt(int val, int low, int hgh) {
    return ((val<low) ? low : ((val<hgh) ? val : hgh));
    }
```

And I would repeat all the code for Y, and manipulate this axis separately.  Otherwise you will need to extend your move method to:

```
public void move(int dltX, int maxX, int dltY, int maxY) {
    positionX=Util.limitInt((positionX+dltX),0,maxX);
    positionY=Util.limitInt((positionX+dltY),0,maxY);
    }
```

Comment: ok.  That makes sense about the drag and drop, but how how how do I constrain the event location?  That is what's driving me nuts.

Comment: Well-That doesn't do what is expected.  Moving the mouse left moves the rectangle right, and vice versa.  Also though it stops at the bounding box, if I reclick and drag again, the rectangle moves off the screen...

Comment: Changing this line: int dx=(px - lastX); fixed the inversion, but I'm still not consistently only hitting the bounding box edge...I get out of the box if I move the mouse around and release the button sometimes, etc.

Comment: @Joel: Also dump dx and px and see if they do anything unexpected.

Comment: sorry-what do you mean dump them?

Comment: @Joel: Print them in a label as you are doing for the event coordinates.

Comment: It's doing what it was before-going negative below 0 and going past the canvas to the right.  Also, to the left, the rectangle does not stop when it's x coordinate reaches 0, but rather when the mouse reaches 0...

Comment: PX: is giving us a steady 0-550 when scrolling from left to right.  Stops at 550 even if I go past the canvas.  DX is fluctuationg between 0 and -1 when moved slowly.  If I move the mouse fast, that number jumps, but gets back to -1.  It becomes 0 at the edges of the canvas.

Comment: @Joel: That is the expected behavior, assuming when you are outside of the canvas dx is always zero; perhaps the problem is in your gobj.move() method.

Comment: What I need to do is know how to compare the gobj.getX(); value and make sure that never goes less than 0 or more than MAX_X.  Right now we are looking at the e.getX().

Comment: PS: I did change the move method too because it needed to contain the y:  gobj.move(dx, 0);

Comment: @Joel: Why not just constrain it's setter/move?  It seems wrong to change the getter to "lie", when the setter should prevent what is an invalid value to begin with.

Comment: man-I'm still a newbie at this, so not sure what you mean? :-(  Can you show me an example?

Comment: @Joel: I extended my answer further; hope it helps.

Comment: just saw this-going to bed now, but I'll take a look at it in the morning.  Thanks!